# Jquery not executing in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium

I am new to ruby on rails and also jquery . I am trying to write an app in ruby that executes a jquery version

I have jquery - rails (2.2.1) gem and also rails (3.2.12) .
I have used a jquery function to unbind submit

Below is the snippet of my code :

```
js_element=driver.find_element(:id=>"<id of my form")
driver.execute_script("('#createAccountForm').unbind('submit')" , js_element)
```

This is the error message 
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok': TypeError: "#createAccountForm".unbind is not a function (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError)

what is it that I may have missed here .??!! Please help

Comment: I think you are missing $ sign. $('#createAccountForm').unbind('submit'). I am not sure though :)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the jQuery function character from your scriot:

```
driver.execute_script("$('#createAccountForm').unbind('submit')" , js_element);
```